# Django Forms: RelatedManager' object has no attribute

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-orm

I have a model defined like this:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='questions')
    text = models.CharField('Question', max_length=255)
    Question_Img = models.ImageField(upload_to='quizzes/', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='answers')
    text = models.CharField('Answer', max_length=255)
    is_correct = models.BooleanField('Correct answer', default=False)
    Answer_Img = models.ImageField(upload_to='answers/', null=True, blank=True)
```

I try to get the image field in a form, however end up resulting in an "RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'Answer_Img'":

```
class TakeQuizForm(forms.ModelForm):
    answer = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Answer.objects.none(),
        widget=forms.RadioSelect(),
        required=True,
        empty_label=None)

    class Meta:
        model = StudentAnswer
        fields = ('answer',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        question = kwargs.pop('question')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['answer'].queryset = question.answers.order_by('text') # THIS WORKS
        self.fields['Answer_Img'].queryset = question.answers.Answer_Img # THIS IS DEFECT
```

I was already able to retrieve the "text" from the Answer-object.. However, it fails to show the "Answer_Img". Goal is to show the image Upload via Form. Does anybody know what the issue is and how to fix it?

Comment: The `Answer_img` field is an ImageField. The queryset attribute is for [fields that handle relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#fields-which-handle-relationships).Thats why it works for `answer` field.

Answer (score 0):

question.answers is a related manager. Its a sort of queryset for Answer instances linked to the current question.

question.answers is not a single instance of answer. So you cannot get an attribute of a model.

What you are basically trying to do is Question.objects.all().text. This cannot be done, you can only get a model attribute on a model instance, not on the queryset instance.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a workaround? I need a picture next to the radiobutton. Thanks.

Comment: It is just not clear what you want to achieve... You have a Answer_Img field that isn't even defined, we don't know anything of the intended functionalities, so I cannot help with what we have.

Comment: The goal is to have a quiz formatted like this:

“ Quiz-Question “ 
-) Text Answer and [Image]
-) Text Answer and [Image]
-) Text Answer and [Image]

Currently, the “Quiz-Question” as well as the “Text Answer” are displayed correctly. However, I somehow cannot retrieve and display the image from the model. Is there a way to query the image in the form? Thanks a lot!